# How can I set a default value for Point datatype parameter but not null in C#

Tags: c#, types, null, default, point

I had a problem with setting default value for parameter which is Point datatype. The Point datatype I initialize like this:

```
public class Point
{
    private double x = 0, y = 0;
    public Point(double x = 0, double y = 0)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

then I build the Rectangle class like this:

```
public class Rectangle {
  protected Point start = new Point();
  private double width = 0, height = 0;
}
```

But I can't build the `constructor` of Rectangle like this:

```
public Rectangle(Point p = null , double w = 0, double h = 0)
{
    this.start = p;
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
}
```

The problem is that the start point of Rectangle will get value `null`, but i can't assign any other specific value for start point. What must I do ?

Comment: How about making `Point`, and possibly `Rectangle` as well, a `struct` instead of a `class`?

Comment: If you don't fancy structs, you could also do: `this.start = p ?? whatever your default Point instance;`

Comment: don’t really get the question… are you asking how check for null? so in the constructor of rectangle just have `if (p is null) p = new Point(0, 0);`

Comment: you do realize .net has in-built point and rectangle classes eg. in the System.Drawing namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=net-6.0 | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle?view=net-6.0

Comment: I think you want `public` instead of `protected` and `private`. Then you can set their values.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Point p {get; set;} = new();
```

That creates a property called p that is of type Point. Get and set and called so it becomes whatever value you assign. The new() at the end is what happens if nothing is assigned. The default state of the variable is a new Point() object. Obviously add in some default parameters to the  new constructor if Point requires it.

Comment: It's not good idea to create private property, use private field instead of private property

Comment: I wrote the answer while waiting in a store. Thank you for catching the mistake.